# EMM managed configuration key values for Boxer email app

Tags: android, outlook, android-management-api, airwatch

I am working on setting up email apps for my enterprise in the EMM work profile created through Android management API. I was able to setup the Gmail app using the managed config details in https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7065453?hl=en.
But I am not able to find such documentations for the Boxer mail or the Outlook app. The gmail app and calendar has been unreliable with some sync issues, so would appreciate some guidance in Boxer mail or Outlook setup through managed configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all applications support or document managed configuration. It’s up to the app developer to implement and document it.
You can try  checking the managed configuration schema for an app  using the [enterprise.application.get](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications/get#http-request) method. It returns a json with the managed properties that the app supports..

For example:

```
 "managedProperties": [
    {
      "key": "com.microsoft.outlook.EmailProfile.EmailAddress",
      "type": "STRING",
      "title": "email address"
    },
    {
      "key": "com.microsoft.outlook.EmailProfile.EmailAccountName",
      "type": "STRING",
      "title": "description for account"
    },
    {
      "key": "com.microsoft.outlook.EmailProfile.ServerHostName",
      "type": "STRING",
      "title": "exchange server url"
    }]
```

Additionally, upon checking the Boxer Mail (com.boxer.email), it doesn’t seem to support any managed configuration.